# Openshift bind TCP port

Tags: python, openshift, tcplistener

I'm trying to deploy a python TCP listener on Openshift but I'm failing to understand how to manage external ports.
Googling and searching on Openshift's own KB, [this article](https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1038-i-cant-bind-to-a-port) is mentioned lots of times but is no longer available. My TCP server app listens on port 8080 (as per $OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_PORT) and I'm trying to connect to it from the Internet on port 8000. Nevertheless, doing this means that a client app can establish a connection even if the server app is not started.

Does anyone have specific information on how to do this?

Comment: Yes, I did. And most of the references point to this link: https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1038-i-cant-bind-to-a-port which is an article that is no longer available on Openshift's KB.

Comment: As you mentioned that your server is listening on TCP/8080, I think then you must be trying to access it on the same port from the internet and not on port 8000. Or have you some sort of layer 3 device performing NAT or port forwarding?

Comment: I listen on port 8080 and try to connect on port 8000 because port 8080 is not accessible from the Internet. According to [Openshift documentation](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-binding-routing.html), I have to do it like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can not make raw tcp connections to your OpenShift gears, you can only make http (80/443) and ws (8000/8443) connections.  Both types of connections go through a proxy on the node, http goes through an apache proxy, and ws goes through a node proxy.  If you want to make raw tcp connections you would have to use port forwarding from your location machine, and make sure that you are publishing the port information through a custom cartridge.

Answer (score 0):

An [Internet Archive grab of the removed KB article you mentioned](http://web.archive.org/web/20140804094125/https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1038-i-cant-bind-to-a-port) says you could bind to internal ports 15000 to 35530. But this has now changed: my test OpenShift box didn't let me bind to *any* localhost port.  Its $OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_PORT is accessible from the outside via normal Web ports (80 and 443; SSL decryption is done for you on 443). If you need other ports you probably need something other than Openshift.

Comment: Note that I answered this from the perspective of Openshift Online 2, which shuts down on 30 September 2017.  Openshift Online 3 is an entirely different system.